# sonarqube process[es] failed to start on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, sonarqube

I'm running Ubuntu Linux 4.4.0-45-generic, and had been running SonarQube 5.6.4 successfully. I wanted to upgrade to 6.2, so I installed it in a parallel directory, and when I run the sonar.sh, it fails with almost no helpful info in the log:

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.12.27 20:42:49 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /home/ubuntu/sonarqube-6.2/temp
2016.12.27 20:42:49 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: 
/usr/lib/jre/jre1.8.0_111/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G 
 -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djna.nosys=true -XX:+UseParNewGC 
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/ubuntu/sonarqube-6.2/temp 
-javaagent:/usr/lib/jre/jre1.8.0_111/lib/management-agent.jar 
-cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /home/ubuntu/sonarqube-6.2/temp/sq-process3726360634491732800properties
2016.12.27 20:42:51 ERROR app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] failed to start
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I've googled and SE'd this error but there's so little to go on I'm not sure what's wrong. I was thinking about trying a JDK instead of the JRE but not sure if that's a waste of time. Same error running this as a normal user or via sudo, BTW. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the earlier SonarServer (5.6.4) still running? Stop the first one, before you start the second.

Comment: Yup, that's it.

Answer (score 4):

Elliott was right. After I did this:

```
sudo ./sonarqube-5.6.4/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh stop
```

...the 6.2 server started normally.

Comment: I posted this answer so I can't upvote it, but it's right.